# How do I format text and create headers when writing to a CSV file in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In Objective C I had this chunk of code that wrote to a CSV file in the format that I specified using ofstream:

```
std::ofstream ofs;
const char header[] = "Time Stamp(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS),Engagement, Theta AF3, Theta AF4, Theta T7, Theta T8, Theta Pz, Alpha AF3, Alpha AF4, Alpha T7, Alpha T8, Alpha Pz, Beta AF3, Beta AF4, Beta T7, Beta T8, Beta Pz, Gamma AF3, Gamma AF4, Gamma T7, Gamma T8, Gamma Pz";

-(void)getResults{

for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
                        if(i!=3){
                            ofs<<AF3[i]<<",";
                            ofs<<AF4[i]<<",";
                            ofs<<T7[i]<<",";
                            ofs<<T8[i]<<",";
                            ofs<<Pz[i]<<",";
                        }
                    }
```

}

```
 -(void)startProgram:(NSString *)firstName next:(NSString *)lastName{
   // thread1 = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(getInsightResult) object:nil];


    //thread2 = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) object:nil];
    //thread1.start;


/*************File .csv stored in folder Document of Application********************/
NSString *path_file_csv = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/AlphaTest_%@_%@.csv",documentDirectory,lastName,firstName];
NSLog(@"Path to file .csv %@",path_file_csv);
ofs.open([path_file_csv cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

ofs << header << std::endl;

[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getInsightResult) withObject:nil];

NSTimer *oneSecTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

}

Thus I am writing to a cell each time with ofs. This allows me to create the header and input values one by one to a cell. How do I do this in swift using swift code only?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you were using Objective-C++, you can still use Objective-C++ and access it from Swift. Or for a pure Swift solution, you can use init(toFileAtPath:append:) of OutputStream.

See Apple's documentation for more details: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/outputstream